# Connection to the database without using the name

Tags: java

What can I do if when my connection to the database does not require a her name in my hosting just a host name . However, when you try to connect by :

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"

        p:url="jdbc:mysql://mysqHostName.pl"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver " p:username="user"
        p:password="password">
 </beans:bean>
```

i have exeception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2145)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2081)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2066)
    at ..........................................................................
```

when i add datebase name i have exeception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'xxxxxx_baza'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
```

Answer (score 0):

`p:url="jdbc:mysql://mysqHostName.pl"` looks dubious at best - this should point to your database.  You need to amend this to be the url of your MySQL db, which I'm assuming is the DB engine you have from the driver you've selected.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the user doesn't have access permission on the database.
Give permission to the user on the database.